# How to match UUID/GUID and replace in logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-filter

I am wanting to group logs by their corresponding HTTP request method, but sometimes these paths contain `ids` as you might expect, currently I have a field `httpPath` which has a value of something like: `resources/12321-2132-asdf3223`, but also could be like : `resources/12321-2132-asdf3223/someaction`. And I want to be able to achieve the following:

```
resources/12321-2132-asdf3223 => resources/{id}
```

And

```
resources/12321-2132-asdf3223/someaction => resources/{id}/someaction
```

Creating a new field: `controllerPath`. So I want to find and replace UUIDs with `{id}`, and store the result in a new field if possible.

Comment: Can you please share your filter config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out myself ( ;

```
  if [httpPath] {
    mutate {
      add_field => { "controllerPath" => "%{httpPath}" }
    }

    mutate {
      gsub => [
        "controllerPath", "(?<GrokParse>/[A-Fa-f0-9]{8}-(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}-){3}[A-Fa-f0-9]{12})", "/{id}"
      ]
    }
  }
```